# How to capture Google Analytics events using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, logging, networking, google-analytics-4

I was trying to capture Google Analytics events using network logs for an ecommerce site. I am seeing them manually but in automated chrome browser events are not showing.

I have enabled network logs and performance logs. Do we need to enable any settings? Can any one please guide me how to solve the issue.
[GA events showing manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVERi.png)

```
 public bool GAEventslogs(string gaEvent)
        {
            var logs = Site.Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");          
            for (int i = 0; i < logs.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(logs[i].Message);
                if (logs[i].Message.Contains("https://analytics.google.com/g/collect") && logs[i].Message.Contains(gaEvent))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;            
        }
```